# Vue JS how to bind checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2

How do we bind checkboxes value using vue js expression ? Below i have the data the filteroptions object and i manage to bind the value to the #html1 i have put below.

What I want to know is how can i bind the checked values to #html2 ? the selected values from the drpdown menu in #html1

As you can see on my filter by on html2 it is not dynamic.

Thank you.

## html1

```
<div class="mh-filter-options">
  <div class="filter-content">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="dropdown" v-for="(opt, item) in filterOptions" :key="item">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
           aria-expanded="false"> {{item}}</a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#" v-for="i in opt" :key="i.value">
            <div class="inner">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label class="filter-label-item">
                  <input type="checkbox" :data-prop="opt" :value=i.value />
                  <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
                  <span>{{i.value}} <span class="badge badge-dark">{{i.count}}</span></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## html 2

```
<div class="filtered-by">
  <div class="filter-title">Filtered By: </div>
  <div>
    <div class="filter-item">
      Year: <span> 2019 </span>
      <a href="" title="Remove Filter"> <i class="fas fas- fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item">
      Model: <span> Escape </span>
      <a href="" title="Remove Filter"> <i class="fas fas- fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item">
      Price range: <span> $5000-$10000 </span>
      <a href="" title="Remove Filter"> <i class="fas fas- fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clear-all-filter">
    <a href="" title="Clear All Filter">Reset Filters</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Method

```
setFilters() {
  this.filterOptions = {
    year: [{ value: '2019', checked: true, count: 10 }, { value: '2013', checked: false, count: 99 }, { value: '2017', checked: true, count: 10 }],
    model: [{ value: 'Explorer', checked: true, count: 8 }, { value: 'Ram 1500', checked: false, count: 4 }, { value: 'Piloto', checked: false, count: 10 }],
    priceRange: [{ value: '$10,000-$20,000', checked: false, count: 5 }, { value: '$20,000-$30,000', checked: false, count: 22 }, { value: '$30,000-$40,000', checked: false, count: 10 }],
    mileage: [{ value: '1-1000', checked: false, count: 10 }, { value: '1001-2000', checked: false, count: 64 }, { value: '2001-3000', checked: false, count: 10 }],
    bodyStyle: [{ value: 'Crew Cab Pickup', checked: false, count: 13 }, { value: 'Quad Cab Pickup', checked: false, count: 9 }, { value: 'Sport Utility', checked: true, count: 2 }]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind checkboxes [with v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox), which takes a boolean value. So in your case it might be `<input type='checkbox' v-model='i.checked'>`

I'm not sure I totally follow your code, particularly the setFilters() method, but the principal of Vue is that you encapsulate all your page state in a model, then html2 just looks at the model value that's 2-way bound to the checkbox. Does that make sense ?